# How to copy data from a stream to a LPCTSTR variable?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm absolutely new to programming. I searched for this question online but couldn't find it anywhere

I'm trying to create window based MFC application using Visual studio 13. I have implemented an OpenFileDialog and obtained the path and file name in a stream. 
Now I need to make it appear in a edittext box using the function SetWindowText. It accepts parameter of type LPCTSTR. So how do I make the conversion or Is there any other better approach for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does that stream come from? Retrieving a filename from an OpenFileDialog never required any streams!?

Comment: Can you tell me the alternative method you are trying to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess around with dynamic allocation here. Simply get the string of the stream and put it into a [`CString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174288.aspx).

It has an [`operator LPCTSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) for this purpose.

```
#include <atlstr.h> //CString
CString csText;
.SetWindowText(csText);
```

Comment: But can you tell me how exactly to put the string of the stream to a CString. I'm ending up getting errors on trying it.

Comment: @abejoe How would I know from your question what your stream is ? You should add that to your question.

Comment: I have included the link of my code with this comment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095515/displaying-the-result-of-a-openfiledialog-in-a-edittext-box

Comment: @abejoe `path = myStream->ToString();` you seem to answer your own question in another question. Also you should mention in your question that you use `.net` and use a stream class from there, else my answer is correct.

Comment: I had actually solved this problem and i'm facing with another error which i have mentioned in the question present in the link. Help me out with that one if possible